# How to print debug messages with Junit ant task?

Tags: xml, ant, junit, verbosity, debug-print

Consider the following `junit` ant target, abridged for readability:

```xml
<target name="junit-tests" depends="clean, compile-tests">
    <junit fork="true" showoutput= ...>

        <classpath>...</classpath>
        <formatter.../>
        <jvmarg value=.../>

        <echo message="${test.dist.dir}"/>

        <batchtest todir=...>
            <fileset dir="${test.dist.dir}">
                <include name="**/*Junit.class"/>
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>
    </junit>
</target>
```

In order to have verbose debug output for the `test.dist.dir` variable, I copied the following line from another target in the `build.xml` file:

```
<echo message="${test.dist.dir}"/>
```

But within the junit test target, it fails with:

```
build.xml:94: junit doesn't support the nested "echo" element.
```

**How do I print debug outputs from a Junit ant task?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it before the `<junit>` element:

```
<target name="junit-tests" depends="clean, compile-tests">
    <echo message="${test.dist.dir}"/>
    <junit fork="true" showoutput= ...>...
```

There is no point to move it inside since the value of the variable can't change.